# How do I fix a list (sometimes incorrect) using a dictionary?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, replace, csv

I'm still struggling to get the commented sections in the *for* loop to work that Klasske suggested below. I included my own test script I've added comments to to explain my thoughts. Any advice would be appreciated.

I have a file (infile1.tsv) which has correct pairings to serve as the dictionary, and I have a file that occassionally has the wrong 1st column (infile2.tsv). I can't just +1 to the column above.

- replace 1st column when not having a "Title_#" where # could be any length
- the junkname could be any string of characters and numbers that doesn't fit the Title_# pattern
- the name to replace from infile2.tsv is listed in infile1.tsv (1st column) with the corrected name (2nd column)

## My Test Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# import dictionary of pairs, then replace those which aren't Title_
# USAGE:  python import_dict_then_replace.py
import csv
import string

infile1_dict = {} # use dict for the library to replace as (key, value)
with open('infile1.tsv','rb') as tsvin:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t') # imports the file as a tsv
    for row in tsvin: # each row in the tab-delimited input file
        infile1_dict.update({row[0]:row[1]}) # use 1st row (0) as key, use 2nd row (1) as value in the dictionary

#print infile1_dict # to verify dictionary is read in correctly

outputstring = [] # use list because it's ordered and can interate through each just once (linear search) to check against the dictionary for replacement
outlist = [] # make another empty list
with open('infile2.tsv','rb') as inlist:
    inputlist = inlist.read().replace('\n','') # gets rid of all newlines to import the rows as list; rstrip('\n') just removes newlines from last lines
    for index, item in enumerate(inputlist): # iterate over each item in inputlist; need the index to reference for each item in the list
        if 'Title_' in item: # when Title_ is in the list's item
            outputstring.append(item) # just put the Title_ item into the list
        if not 'Title_' in item: # when Title_ is not in the list's item
            correction = infile1_dict.get(item, "key was not in dictionary")
            outlist = inlist.replace(item, correction, 1) # replaces the unmatching item with the corresponding value in the dictionary
            outputstring = inlist.append(outlist) # adds to the list
print outputstring
```

### infile1.tsv

```
junk_name1  Title_3
junk-name2  Title_184
junk.name3  Title_122
junkname4   Title_96
```

### infile2.tsv

```
Title_1
Title_2
junk_name1
Title_94
Title_95
junkname4
Title_121
junk.name3
```

### out-complete.txt

```
Title_1
Title_2
Title_3
Title_94
Title_95
Title_96
Title_121
Title_122
```

### out-replaced.tsv

```
junk_name1  Title_3
junkname4   Title_96
junk.name3  Title_122
```

Comment: And [what is your question exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: sorry, I edited the title to clarify: How do I replace to fix a pattern using a libarary of pairs?

Comment: This looks a bit like a ["do my job for me"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198358/stackoverflow-is-not-your-programming-101-teacher) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but is probably not very elegant

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#imports dictionary of pairs, then replaces those which aren't Title_

import csv

infile1dict = {} # dict for the library to replace as (key, value)
with open('infile1.tsv','r') as tsvin:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t') # imports the file as a tsv
    for row in tsvin: # each row in the tab-delimited input file
        infile1dict.update({row[0]:row[1]}) # use 1st row (0) as key, use 2nd row (1) as value in the dictionary
    print (infile1dict)

inlist = [] # list to be tested against the dict library 
with open('infile2.tsv','r') as inlist:
    inlist = [line.strip() for line in inlist.readlines()] # strips off the \n, grabs each line as an item
    print (inlist)

outlist = [] # list for each item to be added into
for item in inlist:
    if 'Title_' in item:
        print 'Item %s will go directly into the output list.' % item
        itmstr = "".join(item) # converts item tuple to item string for append function
        outlist.append(itmstr) # adds item to the output list from input file list
    if not 'Title_' in item:
        print 'Item %s will be replaced with the dictionary.' % item
        correction = infile1dict.get(item, "The inlist's item was not a key in the dictionary.")
        outlist.append(correction) # adds the correction string to the list    
        print('\t'.join(map(str,outlist)))
with open('out-complete.txt', 'w') as outobj:
    outobj.writelines('\n'.join(map(str,outlist)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to understand what you were asking, but I think what you want to do is read first file into a dictionary of key-value pairs:

```
import csv

infile1_dict = {}

with open('infile1.tsv','rb') as tsvin:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    for row in tsvin:
        infile1_dict.update({row[0]:row[1]})
```

Then you'll want to read the second file and replace plus keep track of the replaced values:

```
replaced_values_dict = {}
with open('infile2.tsv','rb') as tsvin, open('out-complete.tsv', 'wb') as tsvout:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    tsvout = csv.writer(tsvout, delimiter='\t')

    for row in tsvin:
        if not 'Title_' in row[0]:
            #write to new file with item found in infile1_dict
            #save pair in replaced_values_dict
        else:
            #write as is
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: This is precisely what I meant to ask! Example script is updated to include your efforts

Comment: So did this answer your question? It seems that you can solve your problem by using the code I wrote here.

Comment: I'm still struggling to get the commented sections in the for loop to work. Any advice would be appreciated.